# Django Channels - self.channel_layer.group_send not calling function

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels, otree

I'm creating a game with chat/voting functionality. I have made it in oTree which is based on  the Django Web Framework. The chat works and is made with Django Channels, in each game a person has a network with other players and needs to vote/answer a question.

I have defined a "send_choice" function in my consumer but when I reference that as the type it never gets instansiated.

**routing.py**

```
from . import consumers
from django.conf.urls import re_path

websocket_routes = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<group_pk>[0-9]+)$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
    re_path(r'ws/network_voting/(?P<player_pk>[0-9]+)/(?P<group_pk>[0-9]+)$', consumers.NetworkVoting)
]
```

**consumers.py**

```
class NetworkVoting(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    def clean_kwargs(self):
        self.player_pk = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['player_pk']
        self.group_pk = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['group_pk']

    async def connect(self):
        self.clean_kwargs()
        # Join
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.connection_groups(),
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()
        print("Connected to Network Socket")

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        self.clean_kwargs()
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.connection_groups(),
            self.channel_name
        )
        print("Disconnected from Network Socket")

    def connection_groups(self, **kwargs):
        group_name = self.get_group().get_channel_group_name()
        personal_channel = self.get_player().get_personal_channel_name()
        return "{}-{}".format(group_name, personal_channel)

    def get_player(self):
        return Player.objects.get(pk=self.player_pk)

    def get_group(self):
        return Group.objects.get(pk=self.group_pk)

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        self.clean_kwargs()
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        msg = text_data_json['message']

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                    "network_voting",
                    {
                        "type": "send_choice",
                        "message": "Hello"
                    }
                )

    async def send_choice(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))

        print("Sent message")
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

To be called by channels when message is sent over a group you need to subscribe to that group.

Since your sending to the `network_voting` you need to subscribe to this.

```
await self.channel_layer.group_add("network_voting", self.channel_name)
```

you also need to unsubscribe to this when you disconnect.

Channels provides a simple way of doing this if your group names are static there is a property `groups` on the instance you can set.

```py
class NetworkVoting(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    groups = ['network_voting']
```

Channels will then take care of subscribing and unsubscribing for you.

Comment: Im facing the same problem. `group_send` is not called. Can you pls look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63916004/cant-send-a-message-to-a-django-channel

Comment: This is not working for me :|